# Check colors in CMYK color space in LR

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, cmyk

I need to see some areas of my photos into CMYK color model. I could manage to see it only in sRGB in Info Panel.

Could you share a way of doing this into Lightroom? May be any plugin will do what I want.

Comment: Do you have specific CMYK profile which you would like to use ?

Comment: No. Any profile will be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know LR do not support CMYK colourspace. So (again) IMHO this is job for PS (as far as I know GIMP do not have good CMYK support)

Please check this [thread](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1133106) from adobe forums

```
Lr does not convert to CMYK. In fact it doesn't even display CMYK profiles.
You can convert to CMYK in Photoshop.
```

Comment: Exporting as CMYK is not what OP asks for.

Answer (score 1):

The feature you are talking about is soft proofing - a program simulates the output of a media with smaller gamut than the display has.

And it is present in Lightroom:

> Once your color profile of choice is within LR, it’s time to use Soft
>   Proofing. Hit ’S’ while within the Develop Module and you’ll see the
>   background behind your image turn white, and the Histogram menu title
>   will change to Soft Proofing, showing the histogram and SP menu below.
>   https://www.slrlounge.com/soft-proofing-lightroom-adobe/

_

> With Soft Proofing enabled, the first time that you make a change to
>   your image, Lightroom presents a dialog asking if you want to “Create
>   virtual copy for soft proofing?” If you choose “Create Proof Copy”,
>   Lightroom automatically creates a virtual copy allowing you to
>   preserve your previous settings (in the master file), and create a new
>   rendition (or version) tailored to the specific soft proofing options
>   that you choose. If you choose “Make this the Proof” Lightroom will
>   make the changes on the master file. Because everything that you do in
>   Lightroom is nondestructive, if you ever choose “Make this the Proof”
>   and then want to undo the changes, in the Develop Module, select
>   Setting > Proof and disable it.
>   http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2014/04/proof-copy-for-soft-proofing-in-lightroom.html

_

And of course you will find more detailed description in the Lightroom manual: https://helpx.adobe.com/pdf/lightroom_reference.pdf (use contents and index to find description of soft proofing)

Answer (score 1):

You currently can't do it with native tools if you use Lightroom version 2015.5/6.6 or newer. The option for a CMYK soft proofing was there up until a point, but Adobe removed it due to some reasons. We are still waiting for them to bring it back.

See https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/lr-2015-6-cmyk-profiles-can-no-longer-be-selected-for-soft-proofing